# Let $a,b$, and $c$ be real numbers. Suppose for every $c$ with $b < c$, we have $a\leq c$. Prove that $a \leq b$.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers. Suppose for every $c$ with $b < c$, we have
>   $a \leq c$. Prove that $a \leq b$.

This is annoying me and I am stuck.

Here is my approach:

Given any $a,b$ that are real numbers either:

1. $a \leq b$
2. $a \geq b$.

Now, in order to prove that (1) is true (my goal), my aim is to prove that (2) must be false.

Now, if $a \geq b$, we know that $a = b$ or $a > b$. If $a = b$, then our conditions imply that with $b < c$, we have $b \leq c$. This can't be true. Now, all that is left to show is that $a > b$ is false. Any ideas?

Comment: Your second condition should be $a > b$. That means there is a $c > 0$ such that $a \ge b+c$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Either is enough to give what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Assume to the contrary that $a>b$, then there exists a $c$ so that $b<c<a$. But this contradicts your assumption. Thus $a \leq b$.

Comment: That is it? WOW! I am an idiot.

Comment: Happens to everyone!